# Which denominations use the King James Version?

Tags: bible, kjv

Which denominations primarily use the King James Version of the Bible?

<sub>I did a search on Google and could not find anything reliable.</sub>

Comment: Most Baptist Churches in our area use it, but it's not universal among Baptists.  I think it tends to be less a denomination thing than a local congregational thing.  I've seen several different denominations use it.  The common thread is a more conservative membership.  Even among more conservative denominations, as the individual Churches within the denomination get more liberal (more contemporary music, for example) they tend to drop the KJV for something newer because that's what the people want.

Comment: See also: [What is the King James only movement?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/284/914).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's really not a *denominational* issue, per se, but a doctrinal issue or a simple preference.

The [King James Only movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_James_Only_movement) are people and churches that believe that the King James version is the only one to use.  They have various reasons for this.

James White has broken it down into five primary reasons for sticking with the KJV:

- **"I Like the KJV Best"** - people who simply like the translation
- **The textual argument** - people who believe that the KJV translation is more accurate because it's based on better manuscripts
- **Received text only** - this belief states that the original manuscripts used by the KJV translation were supernaturally better than the ones we have today.
- **Inspired Translation** - this group believes that there was inspiration behind the translation and that it was, therefore, inspired by God whereas other translations are not.
- **New Revelation** - this group believes that the KJV translation was a new revelation from God.  This view is often called "Ruckmanism", after it's primary adherent, [Peter Ruckman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Ruckman)

Ultimately, it's not a denominational thing, but either a doctrinal issue (that extends beyond denominational decrees) or a preference.

Comment: +1 for both pointing out how this actually an independent doctrinal issue and giving an overview of the reasons behind the stance.

Comment: +1, I'd add to White's list that it's a more poetic read. Although according to David Daniell's "The Bible in English," the KJV scholars had to follow King James I instructions for conformance with the Church of England's ecclesiastic and episcopal agenda. <-- not a major upset for me.

Answer (score 3):

The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints (commonly referred to as the "Mormons" or "LDS") use the KJV. For verification see Scriptures.LDS.org

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Please see [What this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) I hope to see you post again soon.

Answer (score 1):

I am compiling a list of churches (denominations, etc.) that still hold to the KJV (AV) Bible. Any additions and corrections are welcomed!

The Protestant Reformed Church in America, the Free Presbyterian, the Heritage Reformed, Life Bible-Presbyterian churches, and the Apostolic Lutheran Church of America.

Of course, most independent, Fundamentalist churches.

Also The Church of England (Continuing) and some traditional Episcopalians and the Anglican Orthodox Church in this country use the AV/ KJV. (These generally also use the 1662 [Anglican] or 1928 [USA] Book of Common Prayer.)

Comment: Welcome to the site! What follows next has ***nothing*** to do with the quality of your answer (which is good); it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first). As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites). I hope to see you around!